# How to securely escape a string to a filename?

Tags: python, string, path, filesystems, escaping

I want to convert/escape an untrusted string to a filename. The string can contain anything from `*`, `+` and `/` to `../../etc/shadow`, which must not appear in a filename. I also want the filename to be as human-readable (i.e. close to the original string) as possible, so please avoid escaping alphanumeric characters like `Abc123` since they are already valid characters. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 in case it matters.

I am essentially looking for something like `urllib.parse.quote` but for file paths. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you're really close. Why not use `urllib.parse.quote` but with the `safe=''` parameter? That means that `/` will also be encoded. AFAIK that should be safe enough for filenames while still being reasonably readable (readable if it's non-malicious, if it *is* malicious, i.e. with slashes and $ and things, their strings are going to be hard to read).

Comment: You can use the same kind of encoding that's used to create "slugs" in URLs.

Comment: What do you mean by "escape"?  `*` is a perfectly valid character in a filename.  If the untrusted string has an asterisk, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I agree with @JohnGordon, but you should be able to reach your goal with the slugify package (https://pypi.org/project/python-slugify/).